# JQuery Cookies Set Expire Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have this:

```
if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 5 * 1000));
} else {
date = options.expires;
}
expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
```

How to make cookies expire after 10 minutes?

Comment: What plugin are you using for setting / getting the cookies, there are several?

Comment: jquery. nope its single. sry 4 my english :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
 var date = new Date();
 var m = 10;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie("cookie", "value", { expires: date });
```

Alternatively you could use a function:

```
function ExpireCookie(minutes) {
 var date = new Date();
 var m = minutes;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie("cookie", "value", { expires: date });
}
```

Then do `ExpireCookie(10);`

Answer (score 2):

***`10 minutes is 10 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds.`***

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (10 * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });
```