# Set date in cookie expiration

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

How can I set the cookie to expire at this date: 19 Jan 2038 ?

The cookie is not set if I try like this:

```
$.cookie('test', true, {expires: "2038-01-19, 03:14:08 UTC"});
```

Comment: Check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939994/jquery-cookies-set-expire-time

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
  var date = new Date();
  date.setFullYear(2038);
  $.cookie('test', true, {expires: date});
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the number of days from current date to the Date you want your cookie to expire and then set that 'days' value to set the cookie expiry.

```
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date("19 Jan 2038");

// end - start returns difference in milliseconds 
var diff = new Date(end - start);

// get days
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 12:00:00 UTC";

function setUserConfigInCookie(){
  var expireDate = new Date;
  expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 7); // It expires in a week

  var options = {
    path: '/',
    expiresAt: expireDate
  }

  userConfig = {}; // This is a valid JSON object that you need to save in a cookie
  $.cookies.set( 'userConfig', userConfig, options);

  // console.log('Expires=' + expireDate.toGMTString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't as this is a bug with the way browsers handle dates.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27070